# Opentok- how to prevent video from intruder?

Tags: javascript

I am using OpenTok API to create a video chat app. In this app no more that two people should be able to connect to a session at a time.

For that I am Using sessionId to create room and token Id that tells which room you want to connect.

But as I am specifying this session Id in JavaScript, and any intruder can go and view the source of page and can get the `session ID` and can misuse it.

From my understanding if a person gets his hands on a session id it will be as easy as using OpenTOK quickstart tutorial with my session id to snoop my video session.

Can this be prevented?